# New file does not appear on GIT repository

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017, bitbucket

I am learning GIT with bitbucket extension in visual studio( also command line ).
When I change the file Program.cs everything is ok, I can see changes on repository. Next I create new class in new file, stage, commit and push. Then I can see commit message on repository, message about commit a few seconds ago but there is no my new file. I also tried do it in cmd using `git add .`, but it act the same.

Has anyone had similar situations or knows what to do?

EDIT:

> git status

```
On branch second
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/second'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

> git ls-files

```
.gitattributes
.gitignore
ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.sln
ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1.csproj
ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/Program.cs
ConsoleApp1/ConsoleApp1/Test.cs
```

Comment: output of `git status` and `git ls-files`? (add to your question)

Comment: Which file is not appearing?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Test.cs - this is only one file added by myself

Comment: The output seems to show that it is being tracked by git. What are you struggling with?

Comment: @evolutionxbox after commit and push I don't have Test.cs in remote repository

Comment: Are you looking at the “second” branch on the remote?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Yes, I do. I even see commit message and how much time ago the commit was made, but there is no Test.cs file

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me how you are viewing commits in the other repository or repositories, so bear with me for a bit here.

First, remember that when you use Git, you have it create many copies of repositories.  Let's start with a single repository *R* on that exists only on Bitbucket, for instance.  You might, in the command line, run:

```
$ git clone https://bitbucket.com/path/to/R.git my-R
```

(where `$` is the bash shell prompt).  This will create, on *your* computer, a whole new Git repository named `my-R`.  You can now navigate into this directory/folder:

```
$ cd my-R
```

and you will have a bunch of files available.  Git calls this your *work-tree*, because it is where you will do your work.  There is also a hidden directory/folder named `.git` that contains the actual repository itself.

The files that you can view, outside of the hidden `.git`, are not the files that Git uses.  Files inside Git are stored in a special, compressed, Git-only format, usable only by Git itself.  The action verb you use to *get* the files *into* the work-tree is `git checkout`.  When you run `git clone`, the last step of `git clone` is `git checkout`, usually specifically `git checkout master`.

#### Branch names vs commits

The clone itself is a *full copy of every revision of every file*.  So now not only is there a repository *R* on Bitbucket, there is another complete copy of *R* on your own computer.  When you work on files and make commits, you are adding *new* commits to your copy of *R* in `my-R`.  These commits are not (yet!) available anywhere else: they are *unpublished.*

This is true for *branch names* as well.  If you create a new branch name in your repository, that branch name exists in *your* repository.  There are some key differences between branch names and commits, though.

The actual name of a commit is a hash ID.  You may see these hash IDs in `git log` output:

```
$ git log
commit b7bd9486b055c3f967a870311e704e3bb0654e4f
Author: ...
```

Hash IDs are big, ugly, seemingly-random, and impossible for humans to use.  They have to be big and ugly like this, because Git guarantees that every commit gets a unique hash ID all its own, never to be re-used.  So Git offers us the ability to *name* a commit, using a name like `master` or `second`.

The tricky thing about these names is that each name identifies *exactly one commit*.  But we want commits to be in a *series* of commits, one after another.  Git therefore has each commit remember its predecessor or *parent* commit.  Git calls this a *child* of the parent.  Most commits have one parent (one predecessor) and one child (one successor), and these form the chain:

```
... <-F <-G <-H ...
```

where the uppercase letters stand in for hash IDs.

The *branch name*, like `master` or `second`, just remembers the *last* commit in the chain.  If we draw commits from left (earlier) to right (later), all the internal arrows point backwards.  We should therefore put the names on the far right, pointing leftwards to the *tip commit* of the chain:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- second
```

I've stopped drawing the internal arrows because the arrows inside commits can never be changed.  In fact, nothing about any commit can ever change.  The *names*—the `master` and `second` here—can change, and do change all the time; they point to commit `G` at one moment, then commit `H` or `I` a moment later—but the arrows inside commits always point back-and-left to their parent.

#### `git push`

What `git push` does is to send your new commits to some other Git repository.  Your `my-R`, for instance, remembers the URL of its original source *R*, using the name `origin`.  So you can run:

```
$ git push origin second
```

to have Git push your commit `J` (assuming `second` points to `J`) to the Git that holds the original repository *R*.  Commit `J` refers back to commit `I` (`I` is `J`'s parent), and `I` in turn refers back to `G`, so your Git will offer commits `I` and `G` as well.  Presumably, though, you got `G` itself *from* repository *R* at `origin`, so they say: *I already have that one.*  Your Git therefore only has to send `I` (and all its files) and `J` (and all its files) to *R*, and that's the first part of what `git push` does.

Having sent commits `I` and `J`, your Git now asks their Git to set *their* name `second` to point to commit `J` too.  If they don't have a `second` yet, that request can *create* it.  If they do have a `second`, they will check to make sure that your request to move their `second` to point to `J`, instead of whatever it is that it points to right now, is OK.

Assuming they *accept* all of this, and assuming that their `master` still points to commit `G` and not commit `H`—i.e., that your commit `H` is there on *your* `master`, but you have not sent it to *R* to put into *their* `master`—what *they* have now looks like this:

```
...--F--G   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- second
```

(If you send them your `H` and ask them to adjust their `master` to point to `H`, and if they accept that request, then their set of commits and branch names will match yours.)

#### All of this describes the *commits*, but what about their work-tree?

We noted earlier that your work-tree—where you do your work, in your `my-R` copy of repository *R*—is something that *your* Git created.

What about *their* work-tree?  Maybe they do not even have one!  Git supports so-called *bare repositories*, and a bare repository is very simply a repository without a work-tree.  These exist for a simple reason: it's not obvious what to do about a `git push` when someone pushes to the branch that you have checked-out right now and that you are working on.  If you're in the middle of changing or creating a `Test.cs` file, and someone else pushes a commit with a `Test.cs` file in it, what happens to the one you're working on?

(The answer is that your Git generally just refuses the request in the first place.  That way Git does not have to figure out what to do about the file.  So a bare repository has no work-tree, hence has no checked-out copy of the file, and hence there is no concern about clobbering it.)

#### Remember also that your branches—your branch names—are *yours*, and theirs are *theirs*

When you use `git push`, you send *commits* and a request for some other Git to update *their* branch names.  They can accept or refuse the request.  The commits themselves are identified by hash IDs, with each commit having its own unique hash ID, guaranteed to be different from every other commit hash ID, forever.  (That's how Git can tell which commits are new.)  If you use a name they already have, though, and ask that they set it, you're asking them to set *their* name or names.

When you use `git fetch`, you reverse this process: you have your Git call up their Git, and get *from* them, any new commits they have that you don't.  To avoid messing with your branch names, your Git saves *their* branch-name-to-tip-commit mappings by *renaming* their branch names: their `master` becomes your `origin/master`, and their second becomes your `origin/second`.

So, in *your* Git, the way you tell whether their `second` matches your `second` is by comparing your `origin/second`—your Git's memory of their `origin/second`—matches your `second`.  If so, you get the message:

```
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/second'.
```

which is what you saw here.  That means they do have your latest commit, including all of its files.  If you don't *see* your files in their repository, that just means that their *work-tree* isn't associated with that particular commit.  Probably, you need to log on to their machine, navigate to their repository, and run `git checkout second`—assuming they have a non-bare repository.

Remember, though, that once you do that, they may start refusing `git push` operations, because now their Git has to worry about your `git push` changing some file that they—whoever "they" are at this point—is in the middle of working-on.  (Or, of course, they could have a bare repository, but if so, they don't *have* a work-tree ... in which case, what file are you looking at?)